# iOS fastest png picture manipulation at pixel level

Tags: ios, drawing, png

How can i manipulate png pixel values, fast, so that i can display my picture at 30 frames/s

I like to create something like this
Javavscript html canvas example.
http://www.kaotik.si/randomWalk.html

example but i need it in objective-c (iOS) on iPad
I am using ARC.
I like the simplest posible solution.

Comment: You probably aren't going to. It sounds to me like you are going the wrong way about this. Instead try asking how to best achieve what you want instead of how to go about it in the way you think is correct.

Comment: so they are no ways for fast pixel level image manipulations in iOS? creating a picture proceduraly.

Comment: For that sort of thing you are probably going to have to look into opengl.